# ggplot: coord_sf breaks map

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I'm trying to overlay a heatmap on top of the U.S. states shapefile from tigris.  Because the contours extend beyond the limits of the map, I want to increase those limits.  When using `geom_sf()`, `coords_sf()` is the only coords function that can be applied.  However, when I do so, it screws up the map, yielding either a blank map or one where the dimensions are squished.

This is the map without expanding the limits, followed by a reprex for the map minus the density contours.

[image]

````
```
library(tidyverse)
library(tigris)
library(sf)
library(ggthemes)

statemap <- states(cb = T, resolution = "20m")
statemap <- statemap %>%
  filter(GEOID < 60) %>% #territories
  filter(!str_detect(STUSPS, "HI|AK")) #non-contiguous


statemap <- statemap %>%
  st_transform("EPSG:4326")

denver_lat <-  39.7392
denver_lng <- -104.9903


p <- ggplot(data = statemap) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_point(aes(x = denver_lng, y = denver_lat), color = "red") +
  theme_map()

p
```
````

[image]

````
```
p + coord_sf(xlim = c(20, 55), ylim = c(-160, -60)) #expand to include wider geographic area
```
    
![](https://i.imgur.com/vYvCJTu.png)
````

Comment: The reason for why the last line of code results in a blank map is that you confused x and y. It should be `coord_sf(xlim = c(20, 55), ylim = c(-160, -60))`.

Comment: Sorry. Of course: `coord_sf(ylim = c(20, 55), xlim = c(-160, -60))`

Comment: Ugh, what a rookie mistake.  Thanks @stefan